# Java: split() method with pipe special character

Tags: java, regex, split

I have a String = "Hello-new-World". And when i use the split() method with different regex values, it acts differently.

```
String str = "Hello-new-world"
String[] strbuf=str.split("-");
for(int i=0;i<strbuf.length;i++)
 System.out.print(strbuf[i]+" ");
```

The output i get is :

```
hello
new
world
```

whereas if i change my string to "Hello|new|world", i get an altogether different answer. The new output becomes:

```
h
e
l
l
o
|
n
e
w
|
w
o
r
l
d
```

Can someone please explain what could be the possible reason for this.

Comment: Use apache StringUtils it will be accurate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Presumably you're splitting on `"|"` in the second case - and `|` has a special meaning within regular expressions. If you want to split on the actual pipe character, you should escape it:

```
String[] bits = whole.split(Pattern.quote("|"));
```

Answer (score 4):

[split method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) takes regular expression as input. The pipe is a special character for regular expression, so if you want to use it tou need to escape the special character. Ther are multiple solutions:

You need to escape the "pipe" character

```
str.split("\\|");
```

Or you can use the helper quote:

```
str.split(Regexp.quote("|"))
```

Or between sqares:

```
str.split("[|]");
```

Answer (score 3):

Pipe is special regex symbol which means `OR`, if you want to split by pipe then escape it in your regex:

```
String[] strbuf = str.split("\\|");
```

OR

```
String[] strbuf = str.split("[|]");
```

Answer (score 0):

An unescaped `|` is parsed as a regex meaning "empty string or empty string," so use

```
str.split("\\|");
```

`|` having special meaning OR in regex

Answer (score 0):

```
str.split("|");
```

means something different. `String#split` uses [regex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/literals.html), and `|` is a metacharacter, so that string means: split off of the empty string or off of the empty string. That is why your string gets split on every character.

There are a few ways of doing what you expect (use these as the string to split off of):

```
"\\|"
```

Which means to escape the metacharacter.

```
"[|]"
```

Puts the metacharacter in a character class.

```
"\\Q|\\E"
```

Puts the metacharacter in a quote

Answer (score 0):

The pipe has different meaning in regular expression, so if you want to use it you need to escape the special character.

```
str.split("\\|");
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a metacharacter. Escape it with a backslash, like this: `"\\|"`